# python3.6 'listiterator' object has no attribute '__next__',but next() is right?

Tags: python-3.x, generator

`sampe=['ab','ac','ad','bc','bd'] it = smape.__iter__() print(it__next__())`

rasie AttributeError 'listiterator' object has no attribute '**next**
but when I use print(next(it)) return right.

Comment: This is not reproducible. It prints `'ab'` if you correct some errors. Please post the same code that you tried (copy paste). This code will throw many other errors as you have manually typed in your code.

Comment: This has nothing to do with generators, btw. `list.__iter__` returns an iterator which is not a generator